# Can we use Phonetic Analyzer and Synonym maps together in the index of Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to enable both the Phonetic analyzer and Synonym maps together in my search index. But when I worked with both, Synonym mapping is not working.

If I remove the phonetic analyzer as part of the index creation, then the synonyms are working fine.

Also, the synonyms work fine with the inbuilt analyzers like en.microsoft.

**My Index field:**

```
{
  "name": "content",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "facetable": false,
  "filterable": false,
  "key": false,
  "retrievable": true,
  "searchable": true,
  "sortable": false,
  "analyzer": "my_standard",
  "indexAnalyzer": null,
  "searchAnalyzer": null,
  "synonymMaps": [
    "euc-synonymmap"
  ]
}
```

**Analyzer definition:**

```
"analyzers":[
{
  "name":"my_standard",
  "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
  "tokenizer":"standard_v2",
  "tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "phonetic" ]
}
```

]

**Synonym map:**

```
{   
"format":"solr",
"synonyms" : "features,characteristic,property,detail,facet,factor\n
configure,setup,install,launch,arange\n
issue,problem,controversy,affair\n
troubleshoot,fix,correct,fine-tune,over haul\n
extension,postponement,postpone,delay,addition,add-on\n
computer,desktop,system,laptop,mainframe,machine,PC,Workstation\n
temp,temporary,momentary,short lived"
}
```

**Search query:**

```
    {
    "search"="Lane acount postponement",
    "top":"5",
    "highlight":"content"
    }
```

Consider I have a document which is having content with terms 'LAN','account' and 'Extension' that is been indexed in azure index(with phonetic analyzer and synonyms). When I pass search query as "Lane acount postponement", phonetic analyzer analyze 'Lane' term as LAN and 'acount' term as 'account'. It is also highlighting the terms(LAN , account) from document's content since I am using hit highlighting in a search query.

You can see in the synonym map definition,i added **extension** as a synonym for **postponement** . But it is not searching and highlighting the term 'extension'.

I just need to know whether we can use both the Phonetic analyzer and Synonym maps together in a search index.

Please clarify me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the content of your synonym map (or at least enough of it that we could reproduce the issue)?

Comment: Hi Bruce, any update

Comment: Hello Dhanaekaran, Nothing stands out based on your field properties, analyzer configuration and synonym map rule. Can you also include a sample query, expected and actual results?

Comment: Hi Ishan, updated with the sample query